# SharePoint Provider Hosted App linking to server side part

Tags: c#, visual-studio, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I'm creating a provider hosted app for SharePoint.

The app starts with the online part of sharepoint. But i have made a custom ribbon button and want to link to my azure hosted website for the server side part of the app. A direct link isn't working but is there another way to link to the server side part of the app?

```
    <CommandUIHandler Command="Invoke_RibbonCustomAction1ButtonRequest"
                      CommandAction="http://xxxxx.azurewebsites.net/CustomActionTarget.aspx?SPListItemId={SelectedItemId}&amp;SPListId={SelectedListId}"/>
```

I'm linking like the code above but it isn't working.

Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<CommandUIHandler Command="Invoke_RibbonCustomAction1ButtonRequest"
                      CommandAction="javascript:
        function openNewPage()
        {
            var url = 'http://xxxxx.azurewebsites.net/CustomActionTarget.aspx?SPListItemId= {SelectedItemId}&amp;SPListId={SelectedListId}';
            window.open(url);
        }

        openNewPage();
"/>
```

See [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff458385(v=office.15).aspx)

Comment: That's what i'm getting => You do not have permission to view this directory or page.

Comment: You can browse the url directly ? What append if you navigate to the link from your browser ?

Comment: I Cannot browse it directly. Is it possible with a provider app to browse to external pages to perform server Side code

Comment: Check this [MSDN How-To](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp142381(v=office.15).aspx)

Comment: I did this. Can i not link from the Sharepoint online part to the server side code?